# Wordpress PHP get image gallerys URL? I got part of the code working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am trying to create the lightbox gallery in my WordPress, I managed to get most of the code working well for grabbing images out of gallery. However I don't know how to get their URL for their original files....

PHP

```
<?php $post_content = get_the_content();
    preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
    $array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
    $item = 0;
    while ($array_id[$item] != ''){
        if($item == 0){
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($array_id[$item], 'medium');
        }else{
                    echo "<a ref='".wp_get_attachment_image($array_id[$item])."'>";}                        
        $item++;
        }
?>
```

So my idea is to display IMG of a first image in the gallery which I have accomplished with the first ECHO, not for all other images I only want the links to the original files.

My final code needs to look like this:

```
<a rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a rel="group1" href="image_big_3.jpg"></a>
<a rel="group1" href="image_big_4.jpg"></a>
<a rel="group1" href="image_big_5.jpg"></a>
<a rel="group1" href="image_big_6.jpg"></a>
```

Also what would you suggest for rel='' I need this to be unique for every post with galleries I am not sure what to use I can't use TITLE because if they enter more then one gallery with same title there will be issue. I am guessing maybe some sort of (RANDOM) prefix defined by current_time?

Please help 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and edited my code to work:

This is code to accomplish above stated:

```
<?php $post_content = get_the_content();
    preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
    $array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
    $item = 0;
    while ($array_id[$item] != ''){
        $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($array_id[$item]);
            if($item == 0){
                echo "<a href='".$url[0]."'>".wp_get_attachment_image($array_id[$item], 'gallery-thumb')."</a>";
            }else{
                echo "<a href='".$url[0]."'</a>";}                      
        $item++;
        }
?>
```

Reference used: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Thank you all!